# Is MariaDB 10.1 compatible with Doctrine 2.5?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb

I'm starting a new PHP project with Symfony 3 and Doctrine 2 and I would like to use MariaDB 10.1 (or 10.0) instead of MySQL 5.7, but i cannot find if Doctrine (ORM) 2.5 supports MariaDB 10.1 and, if not, if there's any plan to support it in the future.

Does anyone know more? Known incompatibilities, future plans, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For all intents and purposes, `MariaDB 10` is identical to `MySQL 5.6`, so you should be good to go.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

> MySQL 5.5 is compatible with MariaDB 5.5 and also in practice with MariaDB 10.0. What this means is that:
>
> - Data and table definition files (.frm) files are binary compatible.
>     See note below for an incompatibility with views!
> - All client APIs,
>     protocols and structs are identical.
> - All filenames, binaries, paths,
>     ports, sockets, and etc... should be the same.
> - All MySQL connectors
>     (PHP, Perl, Python, Java, .NET, MyODBC, Ruby, MySQL C connector etc)
>     work unchanged with MariaDB. There are some installation issues with
>     PHP5 that you should be aware of (a bug in how the old PHP5 client
>     checks library compatibility).
> - The mysql-client package also works
>     with MariaDB server.
> - The shared client library is binary compatible
>     with MySQL's client library.
>
> This means that for most cases, you can just uninstall MySQL and install MariaDB and you are good to go.

Just beware that since Maria DB 10.0, not all features in MySQL 5.6 are available. A detailed comparison between MariaDB 10.1 and MySQL 5.7 can be found here:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/system-variable-differences-between-mariadb-101-and-mysql-57/